# Is there a chat for Tensorflow users?

Tags: tensorflow

I've been directed here by https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!forum/discuss for help.

Is there an IRC channel or mailing list or anything less structured to find answers to my simple questions?

Comment: Reddit is more active for sure. Not really a SO question though ... Try https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

There's [##tensorflow](https://irc-source.com/channel/freenode/%23%23tensorflow) IRC channel at freenode, but not many people there...